# Why do I get an incorrect value for MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE in Authority Record query response?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I have the following code for querying authority records from MQ.

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
agent.setCheckResponses(false);
PCFMessage[] responses;
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_AUTH_OPTIONS,
MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_ALL_MATCHING + MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_ENTITY_EXPLICIT + MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_AS_WILDCARD);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCACF_AUTH_PROFILE_NAME, "*");
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE, MQConstants.MQOT_ALL);
responses = agent.send(request);
```

When I process the response I get a value of `1017` for the parameter `MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE`.
The documentation show only the following values for `MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE`

```
MQOT_ALIAS_Q    1002
MQOT_ALL    1001
MQOT_AUTH_INFO  7
MQOT_CF_STRUC   10
MQOT_CHANNEL    6
MQOT_CLNTCONN_CHANNEL   1014
MQOT_CURRENT_CHANNEL    1011
MQOT_LOCAL_Q    1004
MQOT_MODEL_Q    1003
MQOT_NAMELIST   2
MQOT_PROCESS    3
MQOT_Q  1
MQOT_Q_MGR  5
MQOT_RECEIVER_CHANNEL   1010
MQOT_REMOTE_Q   1005
MQOT_REQUESTER_CHANNEL  1009
MQOT_RESERVED_1 999
MQOT_SAVED_CHANNEL  1012
MQOT_SENDER_CHANNEL 1007
MQOT_SERVER_CHANNEL 1008
MQOT_STORAGE_CLASS  4
MQOT_SVRCONN_CHANNEL    1013
```

Why am I getting a value `1017`?
Could this be a combination of various other values?
 If yes how do I know which ones?, because I can arrive at the number `1017` through several combination of the above values.

Comment: Not sure where you got your documentation from, the valid responses for that command are here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087320_.htm This includes MQOT_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME as mentioned by JasonE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q092140_.htm

1017 is MQOT_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME

For completeness, here's the list of MQOT_ constants from a 9.0.0.0 installation

```
#define MQOT_NONE                      0
#define MQOT_Q                         1
#define MQOT_NAMELIST                  2
#define MQOT_PROCESS                   3
#define MQOT_STORAGE_CLASS             4
#define MQOT_Q_MGR                     5
#define MQOT_CHANNEL                   6
#define MQOT_AUTH_INFO                 7
#define MQOT_TOPIC                     8
#define MQOT_COMM_INFO                 9
#define MQOT_CF_STRUC                  10
#define MQOT_LISTENER                  11
#define MQOT_SERVICE                   12
#define MQOT_RESERVED_1                999
#define MQOT_ALL                       1001
#define MQOT_ALIAS_Q                   1002
#define MQOT_MODEL_Q                   1003
#define MQOT_LOCAL_Q                   1004
#define MQOT_REMOTE_Q                  1005
#define MQOT_SENDER_CHANNEL            1007
#define MQOT_SERVER_CHANNEL            1008
#define MQOT_REQUESTER_CHANNEL         1009
#define MQOT_RECEIVER_CHANNEL          1010
#define MQOT_CURRENT_CHANNEL           1011
#define MQOT_SAVED_CHANNEL             1012
#define MQOT_SVRCONN_CHANNEL           1013
#define MQOT_CLNTCONN_CHANNEL          1014
#define MQOT_SHORT_CHANNEL             1015
#define MQOT_CHLAUTH                   1016
#define MQOT_REMOTE_Q_MGR_NAME         1017
#define MQOT_PROT_POLICY               1019
#define MQOT_TT_CHANNEL                1020
#define MQOT_AMQP_CHANNEL              1021
#define MQOT_AUTH_REC                  1022
```

Comment: thanks for the link, I will try this can comment of the result.

Comment: I changed my code to take into account all the possible values in the documentations, but now, I get a value of 9 that is not present in this list. Any ideas?

Comment: I have looked at docs for MQ v9, 8 and v7.5. None of them have a value of 9.

Comment: Where are you looking for these constants - make sure you have a v9 (even if its a locally installed client for the headers)... MQOT_COMM_INFO is 9, which is listed in the object type responses in here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087320_.htm